# Use casting to solve Raw use of parameterized class

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, oop, apache-spark-mllib

In spark mllib there are some classifers algorithm like Random Forest, Gradient-Boosted Trees, etc. I try to general before and after process then only change algorithm class for each time.

```
train(ProbabilisticClassifier<Vector, ? extends Predictor, ? extends Transformer> classifier) {
    ...
    classifier.setLabelCol(myLabel).setFeaturesCol(myFeatures)
    ...
}
```

which then I can pass

```
GBTClassifier gbtClassifier = new GBTClassifier()
train(gbtClassifier)
```

I need to custom paramenters for setLabelCol() and setFeaturesCol(). Predictor abstact class contains these 2 function. That why I have to use:

```
ProbabilisticClassifier<Vector, ? extends Predictor, ? extends Transformer> classifier
```

But keyword Predictor show the message "Raw use of parameterized class". Predictor require some castings and also self casting.

I can still run code well but I guess there some potential issue with that.

Predictor class from spark java doc [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/Predictor.html)

Comment: I think you already know the problem, the `Predictor` has 3 type parameters, while you're just using the type itself, so that's a compile warning, and you're right, it MIGHT result in some issues somewhere in your code during runtime. I think you can use some wildcards to fix this `..., ? extends Predictor<?, ? extends Predictor<?, ?, ?>, ?>, ...` maybe?  I'm not sure,  have not done java in a while now :)

Comment: @AminMal Thank you. I read generic and wildcard few days ago. Your solution help me. I guess I should deepen more.